# How to connect a remote client to my corba server in java using IP?

Tags: java, corba

I have a Corba application in Java working on my PC. Both the client and server running on one PC. Now I want the server and client running on different PCs and establishing a connection between them but I'm not sure how to do it I tried looking for a solution online but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you pass the object reference to your client you can put your server on any machine. You could pass the IOR as a stringified form (e.g. IOR:....) or as a corbaloc string.

For example see https://github.com/JacORB/JacORB/tree/master/demo/hello